# Is there a way to echo a Powershell command line?

Tags: powershell

I've got several Powershell scripts under construction, and one thing I'd like to do in them is spit out a line at the top of the output echoing the command line used.

Use case is: output is being redirected to a file, and a year from now when someone examines that file, I want them to be able to copy/paste the command from the output file to regenerate the same output where the only differences are chronological.  [ Okay, that was a little too generic ... first case: I'm examining ACLs and want to be able to repeat the same examination on the newer data at any point in the future by simply copy/pasting the same command. ]

My script begins with the parameter definitions:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [string] $filter="Name -like '*'",
    [string] $user=$null,
    [switch] $test01=$false,
    [switch] $test02=$false
)
```

What I'm doing now is a fall-back position, knowing what parameters can be accepted, I'm dumping out the names & values of those parameters:

```
if ($user.Length -eq 0) { $u = "NULL" } else { $u = "|$user|" }
if ($test01) { $u += ", -TEST01" }
if ($test02) { $u += ", -TEST02" }
"RUN BEGINS at $((get-date).ToString('F')) -- Filter is |$filter|, User is $u"
```

Ugly, hacky, not even a hint of portability in it, and definitely NOT a copy/paste of the command.

Regardless, this CAN be mangled into a command line; but not generically, and not with 100% surety.

I've tried using $args, but apparently the either defining named parameters or the CmdletBinding() breaks that mechanism, because it's always empty.  Tried $PsBoundParameters, Get-History, and even $0 .. $9 bash-like variables.  So far, nothing I can find gives the command line that launched the script that's running.

$PsBoundParameters is close, it's got all the right data as key,value pairs that could be built up into a command line. but it still isn't a command line, and would require mangling to get it into one.

Get-History came even closer as it includes a complete command line; problem is it gives the command run RIGHT BEFORE the command that launched the script, not the command that launched it.

Running out of options ... but am way open to suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Found it! And it was as simple as I'd hoped it would be.  [ to use ... finding it was a pain ]

`$MyInvocation.Line`

Answer (score 1):

While I agree that `$MyInvocation.Line` will get the literal command used which seems to be what you want on the surface, I'd still argue that the data in `$PSBoundParameters` is more useful long term simply because you can't guarantee users will call your function in a way that makes the command line actually useful.

Consider the common case where callers have declared variables to hold parameter values:

```bsh
$myfilter = "Name -like '*Joe*'"
MyFunction -filter $myfilter
```

Consider the case where callers create a hashtable to splat with:

```bsh
$myParams = @{
    filter = "Name -like '*Joe*'"
    test01 = $true
}
MyFunction @myParams
```

If you only record the command line, you'd lose the parameter data in both of these cases. And if you really want a literal command that people can copy/paste from the log, it shouldn't be that hard to generate a synthetic command based on the data in `$PSBoundParameters`. It doesn't have to be literally the same command as long as the same parameter data gets passed in, right?

Comment: Technically correct, which is, of course, the best kind of correct. :-)

It is true that using ````$PSBoundParameters```` I can cover more convoluted call patterns, I don't expect either variables or hashtables to be in use, and was looking for the literal text of the command.  I even had a decent command re-creation function going, but dropped it for the ````$MyInvocation.Line```` option.